# PostgreSQL swedish sorting

Tags: macos, postgresql, sorting, locale

How do I sort by swedish character set in PostgreSQL?

```
select name from category 
order by lower(name) collate "sv_SE.UTF-8";
```

This is the result, which is wrong – `Äää` and `Ååå` should switch places.

```
Aaa
bbb
Ccc
Äää
Ååå
Ööö
```

Tested on OSX and PostgreSQL 9.4.5. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Also tested `LC_ALL=sv_SE.UTF-8 sort test.txt` but get the same results, so it might be a bigger issue.

Comment: I'm not Swedish but (in UTF-8): Ä=c384 and Å=c385. I guess this explain the sort order shown here above. This has nothing to do with neither OSX nor Postgres... It's the encoding.

Comment: I believe that collation support is delegated to the operating system; if Postgres is getting it wrong, it's because OSX is getting it wrong.

Comment: PostgreSQL uses the underlying operation system's locale support when you use collations other than `C` / `POSIX`. I've found only [this related thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2346537?tstart=0); if you can, pls. check that your `sv_SE.UTF8` locale on OSX is not just a symlink to `la_LN.US-ASCII`

Comment: @pozs Thanks, how would I do that?

Comment: @Znarkus Sorry, I'm no OSX expert, but you could ask a similar question on http://serverfault.com or http://superuser.com

Comment: @pozs You were right `LC_COLLATE@ -> ../la_LN.US-ASCII/LC_COLLATE` I guess it's an OSX bug.